# loop through mapbox getDirections to populate a route array

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am trying to loop through an array called directions each index containing two arrays, latitude at index 1 and longitude at index 0 and add the results from the mapbox.getDirections to a route array to plot a route on the map. Below is my code:

I believe I am facing synchronicity issues and mapbox.getDirections callback doesn't respond in time, so I am getting weirdness routes, if the route is greater than 1.

```
for (let i = 0; i < directions.length - 1; i++) {
                let fromIndex = i;
                let toIndex = fromIndex + 1;
                let directionParams = [
                    { latitude: directions[fromIndex][1], longitude: directions[fromIndex][0] },
                    { latitude: directions[toIndex][1], longitude: directions[toIndex][0] }
                ]
                let self = this;
                mapbox.getDirections(directionParams, getDirectionsParams).then(function (results) {
                    let routes = results.entity.routes[0].geometry.coordinates;
                    let newRoute = self.state.route.concat(routes);
                    self.setState({
                        route: newRoute,
                    })
                });
            }
```

This method is supposed to be array-size agnostic, so if the array is 4 indices, it will extract the directions from index 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, therefore displaying 3 routes in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the logic, you can move the promises outside of the loop, and resolve them all together with `Promise.All`

```
const yourFunction = async () => {

  const arrayOfDirections = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < directions.length - 1; i++) {
    const fromIndex = i;
    const toIndex = fromIndex + 1;
    const directionParams = [
      { latitude: directions[fromIndex][1], longitude: directions[fromIndex][0] },
      { latitude: directions[toIndex][1], longitude: directions[toIndex][0] }
    ];
    arrayOfDirections.push(directionParams);
  }

  const promises = [];
  arrayOfDirections.forEach((directionParams) => {
    promises.push(mapbox.getDirections(directionParams, getDirectionsParams));
  });

  const arrayOfresults = await Promise.all(promises);
   // here you have array of results returned by your promises
};
```

Comment: yes, thank you kindly! one thing to note is since I'm using react I had to import regeneratorRuntime to make async/await functionality work.

Comment: @ksenia oh sorry I forgot to mention that.. but you can always use normal promises like this `Promise.all(promises).then(results=>{});`